# Unmet dependencies when trying to install curl on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, curl

When trying to install curl on Ubuntu 16.04, it gives me the following error message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
curl : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.47.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to fix?

Comment: Do `sudo apt update; sudo apt-get upgrade` helps ?

Comment: Please add the output of `apt policy curl libcurl3-gnutils` to your question.

Comment: How about `apt install -f`?

Comment: The output is: curl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.47.0-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     7.47.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
N: Unable to locate package libcurl3-gnutils

Comment: Wallace : Did you forget `sudo apt update` ? I.e. latest is curl 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.6 , not 7.47.0-1ubuntu2 → https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/curl

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE:
I fixed the problem by reverting to an older version of libcurl3-gnutls.

For anyone who is having the same problem, I did this by listing the cache:

```
apt-cache showpkg libcurl3-gnutls
```

Which gave me a long output, but the important part was the last three lines:

```
Provides: 
7.47.0-1ubuntu2.6 - 
7.47.0-1ubuntu2 - 
Reverse Provides:
```

I used the following command to download the older version:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-gnutls=7.47.0-1ubuntu2
```

Then I ran `sudo apt install curl` as normal.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm getting Version '7.47.0-1ubuntu2' for 'libcurl3-gnutls' was not found error

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something similar but the fix suggested above didn't work. What finally fixed it for me was to do:
sudo apt remove libcurl4
then I could do
sudo apt upgrade
without getting error messages about unmet dependencies for libcurl.